# I am trying to store questions from php into a MongoDB backend, then call the questions and options from the database

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb, function, mongodb-query

How would I call the questions from Mongo with the associated "Options" and associate a score if the correct "answer" is selected. Could anyone help with this? Also it seems to continuously add the array every time the page is refreshed, how would I resolve this?

```
<?php 
    function createGKQuiz(){
    $quiz = array(
        "Question" => 'Puffin is a',
        "Option" => 'Bird', 'Crossing', 'Penguin',
        "Answer" => 'Bird',
        "Question" => 'Grice is northern english for',
        "Option" => 'Young Pig', 'Gravy', 'Gravy & Rice',
        "Answer" => 'Young Pig'
    );
    $quizconnection->insert($quiz);
}
?>
```

From Mongo Interface I can see one of the questions have been added but the question before doesn't appear to have been inserted into the collection.

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5542c010d8291b04108b456c"), 
    "Question" : "Grice is northern english for", 
    "Option" : "Young Pig", 
    "0" : "Gravy", 
    "1" : "Gravy & Rice", 
    "Answer" : "Young Pig" 
}
```

Comment: you want to find the record by matching option ?

Comment: do you know how I could associate the "answer" with the "Option"? So that when the "answer" is selected I can associate a score with it

Answer (score 0):

```
    Try:
    $quiz1 = array(
        "Question" => 'Puffin is a',
        "Option" => array('Bird', 'Crossing', 'Penguin'),
        "Answer" => 'Bird'
    );
    $quizconnection->insert($quiz1);
    $quiz2 = array(
        "Question" => 'Grice is northern english for',
        "Option" => array('Young Pig', 'Gravy', 'Gravy & Rice'),
        "Answer" => 'Young Pig'
    );
$quizconnection->insert($quiz2);
```